google sheets .ico, .png, .svg images all fail when copy/paste to google sheets
We have a simple table based grid on an html page that contains a few icons which are about 1KB in size.
Our end users have copied and pasted info out of this table into google sheets for about 10 years now.
As of last week (around 10/28/24) google sheets is unable to handle copy and paste operations from this html table into a google sheet as long as the icons are in place.
When we hit about 200-500 rows of data google sheets just tosses 'out of memory' exception on the cut and paste operation.
We have found if we strip out the small 700byte - 1K sized icons we have in place (we have 3 in total -  the cut/paste works without issue.  If i remove all icons except one icon i still have the same out of memory exception.
I replaced every icon with png files and svg files and tried different file types and this does not help - still throw out of memory exception.
I created a completely blank html table in asp.net razor just to generate a simple 1000 row table
@for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
     <tr>
         <td>Test entry</td>
         <td>@i</td>
         <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/icons/pencil.png")" alt="edit" /></td>
     </tr>
 }

using a simple sample like this i can copy about 300 rows and once i get to about 400-500 rows sheets throws out of memory exception.

This appears to be a newer issue here with us though i have seen random reports of this back to 2021 with google sheets.
Several things we have tried that work
1 - Copy->Paste Special->Values Only
2 - copy and paste into VS Code - works in 1 second. You can then copy paste to google sheets from there because the images have been eliminated and this works fine.
Anyone have any ideas if google has modded something with the clipboard perhaps that may be causing mass out of memory exceptions when trying  to paste data into google sheets?
Update:
If you attempt to do this in another browser  (in this instance Edge) then you receive this

followed by the final error


That "aw snap" message is a Chrome error message. It's Chrome that's crashing, not Sheets per se. What happens if you use another browser?

As per @zmccord, this is indeed a Chrome error message. You may refer to this documentation.

thank you - the same issue occurs in other browsers.  I just updated the write up with details and screenshots from edge - good call out.    We can duplicate this in all systems we have tried (roughly 15 different systems now) using a very simple html page with a table containing 1 icon and 1000 rows.

If you think the problem is at Google's end and the link to the troubleshooting steps I provided in the comment above still doesn't resolve the issue, you can file a report on the issue tracker using this link.

Thank you - we created a simple html file with a very simple icon and sent a working sample to google.
